# Code won't execute in do while loop in C

Tags: c, do-while

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
printf("\nCommand? ");
ret = scanf("%c", &command);
do
{
    // printf("Command? ");
    // ret = scanf("%c", &command);
    if (ret != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input!\n");
    }

    if (command == 'd')
    {
        result = dequeue(&queue1, &entry);
        if (result == 1)
            printf("%d was dequeued\n", entry);
        else if (result == 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: attempt to dequeue from an empty"
                    " queue\n");
    }
    else if (command == 'e')
    {
        ret = scanf("%d", &add);
        result = enqueue(q, add);
    }
    else if (command == 'q')
        break;
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid command!\n");

    printf("Queue:");
    for (int i = 0; i < q->end; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d", q->element[i]);
    }
    printf("\nCommand? ");
    scanf("%c", &command);
} while (command != 'q');
```

Then here is the partial GDB log:

```
146             printf("Command? ");
(gdb)
147             ret = scanf("%c", &command);
(gdb)
Command? d
148             if (ret != 1)
(gdb)
153             if (command == 'd')
(gdb)
155                 result = dequeue(&queue1, &entry);
(gdb)
156                 if (result == 1)
(gdb)
158                 else if (result == 0)
(gdb)
159                     fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: attempt to dequeue from an empty"
(gdb)
ERROR: attempt to dequeue from an empty queue
172             printf("Queue:");
(gdb)
173             for (int i = 0; i < q->end; ++i)
(gdb)
177             printf("\nCommand? ");
(gdb)
Queue:
178             scanf("%c", &command);
(gdb)
179         } while (command != 'q');
(gdb)
```

as you can see, the line 172 `printf("Queue:");` won't get executed, as well as the rest of the code. I cannot figure out why.

I typed d into *command*

Could someone help me explain this? Thanks.

Comment: Er... Because you `break` out of the loop right before? In any case, the code is messy. It should be made simpler, clearer and less error prone. Even if it worked.

Comment: I type 'd' into *command*, not 'q'.

Comment: Are you sure the print statement is not executing? I would guess that q is null and your problem is q->end. You wont see the printf because of i/o flush issue. try putting fflush(stdout); after your printf

Comment: Why are you fetching `command` at the beginning and end of every loop? Surely once per loop is sufficient?

Comment: Why are all these "break" answers getting upvoted? clearly that is not the issue.

Comment: Anyway, you should begin by putting `{}` around each `if` and `else` clause. Otherwise your code is hard to follow and error prone.

Comment: Yes, because for loop doesn't get executed, the final scanf() doesn't get executed. Well at least it didn't ask me for further input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all.

I think I've figure it out how: just to write another function to print out all the results.

So the modified code is like this:

```
do
{
    ret = fgets(buf, BUF_LENGTH, "%c %d", &command, &add);
    if (ret != 1 && ret != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input!\n");
        continue;
    }

    if (command == 'd')
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (command == 'e')
    {
         ...
    }
    else if (command == 'q')
        break;
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid command!\n");

    /* Printing out the queue elements */
    print_element(q);

    printf("Command? ");
} while (command != 'q');
```

I know my code is messy, I am still a beginner of C programming language. I am in the progress of learning pointers.

There are some modifications in the "..." part of code, but I believe the changes are not related to I/O.

Thank you all for suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think your concern is that the `printf` is traced in the debugger but no output is produced.  This is probably because `printf` calls send output to `stdout`, which is usually buffered, so output may not appear until later when running in gdb.  In some systems, the buffer is flushed when a newline is seen.  So you might try adding `\n` to the end of `"Queue:"`.  Or `fflush(stdout);` after the print will definitely cause the printf to work. Output to `stderr` is not buffered.  That's why you see that output immediately.

Comment: The scanf at the bottom didn't get executed, it didn't ask me for input in GDB.

Comment: @hlx98007  That's also a buffering problem.  The second scanf is getting the newline you typed after the first character.  One way to deal with that is to say `scanf(" %c", &ch);`.  The space before %c should purge all whitespace from the buffer before getting the next character.

Comment: `One way to deal with that is to say scanf(" %c", &ch);` 
Wonder why my answer got downvoted - was the first one to answer and point this out.

Answer (score 3):

It is executed, as you can see in your single stepping of the code in the debugger. It doesn't print right away because printf() output is kept in a buffer until the buffer is full or until a newline is encountered. Either put a newline at the end or fflush(stdout) afterwards if you need to see the output immediately.

Answer (score 0):

After examining your code, the only solution I can come up with is that your condition in the for loop `q->end` is <= 0

Comment: That is correct. But it didn't ask me for input at the code's end inside the do-while loop. I don't know why.

Comment: Yes but I don't know what kind of input your are giving the program. In terms of giving the program characters, there is a [better way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19508850/2089675) to read characters from the stdin that ignores newline characters. I suggest this because that might be the case with your scanf is reading the newline character as well and you are thinking it is doing nothing

Comment: You are right. I had the assumption that scanf ignore the newline I typed. I will change that.